# What is the c-style atomic free function like std::atomic_is_lock_free for?

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

I understand that `std::atomic_is_lock_free` is c-style free function corresponding to `std::atomic<T>::is_lock_free`.

But the parameter of this function is like `std::atomic_is_lock_free(const std::atomic<T>*)`.
The `std::atomic<T>` is not c-style syntax so `std::atomic_is_lock_free` can't be used in c files anyway.

So why is this c-style free function introduced? What is the usage of this?

Edit:
Below is explanation from C++ Concurrency in Action.

> ***The free functions are designed to be C-compatible***, so they use pointers rather than references in all cases. For example......

It says free function is for C-compatibility. But I can't think of a good example.

Comment: cppreference.com documentation for this is a mess.  What in the world does "The argument is pointer to a volatile atomic type" mean?  Pointers have type and point to objects.  They do not point to types; in C++ you cannot take the address of a type.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Presumably they just mean "pointer to *an object of* volatile atomic type"?  It's slightly imprecise but doesn't really seem ambiguous.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Ahh, but I might like to call `atomic_is_lock_free((A*)nullptr)` and inserting those magic words "to an object" prevents that.

Comment: @BenVoigt AFAICT this is not allowed because the freestanding function is specified to call the member function.

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be any difference, as both functions need an actual object according to [the draft language](https://eel.is/c++draft/atomics#lockfree-3) which even gives the exact same description for both.

This seems to be a holdover from before the requirement "the result of the lock-free query is the same for all atomic objects of the same type"... given that requirement it would be useful to be able to query a type without having any object instance.